# Find The MAX of SUM in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sum, max

good day guys
currently I'm making PHP(inventory management) for my items, in my system customers can buy items , I save customer ID and number of sold Items in one table (called it Sell table) in MySQL , now I want to show the best customer.(who bought the most items in my system)
I wrote a code to find out how many items each customer bought ,but I don't know how I can show the best customer 
see this code :

```
$test= "SELECT c_id, SUM(n_sell) FROM sell GROUP BY c_id "; 
$resut = mysql_query($test) or die(mysql_error());
while($t = mysql_fetch_array($resut)){
    echo "Number of sold: ". $t['SUM(n_sell)'] ." to". $t['c_id'] .":id of customer";
    echo "<br />";
}
```

It shows all of my customers with numbers of sold items to them, I need to show the specific customer who has the maximum number of sell item .
for example, this is my result :

> Number of sold: 11 to 2 :id of customer 
>   Number of sold: 103 to 3: id of customer

but the thing I want is just show :

> Number of sold :103 to 3 :id of customer

I hope you guys can get me,
thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$test = "SELECT c_id, MAX(Bought) AS MaxBought FROM (SELECT c_id, SUM(n_sell) AS Bought FROM sell GROUP BY c_id) AS tmp HAVING MAX(Bought) = tmp.Bought"; 
$resut = mysql_query($test) or die(mysql_error());
while($t = mysql_fetch_array($resut)){
    echo "Number of sold: ". $t['MaxBought'] ." to". $t['c_id'] .":id of customer";
    echo "<br />";
}
```

Here is the SQL query alone for easier understanding:

```
SELECT c_id, MAX(Bought) AS MaxBought
FROM (SELECT c_id, SUM(n_sell) AS Bought
      FROM sell
      GROUP BY c_id) AS tmp
HAVING MAX(Bought) = tmp.Bought
```

Comment: In case there are several best customers with equal amount of bought items, this code will show all of them. The one by hjpotter92 won't.

Answer (score 1):

There are two methods for that(which I can think of). Both need change in your SQL query.

Sol. 1

```
$test= "SELECT c_id, MAX( SUM(n_sell) ) FROM sell GROUP BY c_id ";
```

Sol. 2

```
$test= "SELECT c_id, SUM(n_sell) FROM sell GROUP BY c_id ORDER BY SUM(n_sell) DESC LIMIT 1";
```

The remaining section of your code may remain the same.

Comment: Thanks , I wrote the first method  before,It dosen't work in my system ,don't know why , but second one is new for me , thanks alot. It works....

Comment: The `MAX(SUM( ))` will not work as you expect. Please edit your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`ORDER BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html) .